# Rogue Trader RPG NPC Wounds

Tags: npc, rogue-trader

hopefully you folks can answer this for an older game system I've been trying to run.  I'm new to this so maybe I'm missing something.  To start, I don't know if the wounds listed on statblocks are correct or if they are, how these numbers are getting so high.  Just as an example, General Dante (The Frozen Reaches campaign book) has a Toughness bonus of 41 and 30! wounds.  He has sound constitution listed once in his statblock for 1 extra wound, so where are all these wounds coming from?

As another example, Rogue Trader Blitz has a TB of 3, 26 wounds and no sound constitution.  Rogue Trader Orleans has a TB of 4 and 24 wounds and no sound constitution.  How does this make sense?  I realize you can get a difference of a few wounds based upon starting choices and good/bad rolls, but is this really correct?  Even if I assume maximum possible starting wounds on generation my numbers are nowhere near this.

So I guess that just leaves the question of, if these are accurate what am I missing in character generation / leveling that would account for this?  I can't really assume Dante took Sound Constitution 15 times, since that doesn't seem allowed in the rules.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know for sure, but the idea that NPCs have to be built like PCs and follow PC rules is not universal and especially older games just make up values that seem appropriate for the challenge the adventure is supposed to provide. Rogue Trader might do so, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confident you are misreading the statblock. A *toughness* of 41, absent of the *Unnatural Characteristic (Toughness)* trait, gives a toughness bonus of 4, and that toughness bonus isn't listed separately, you are expected to read the tens digit of the full characteristic.

A *toughness bonus* of 41 is mathematically impossible in the Rogue Trader ruleset, as 41 is a prime number over 10.

NPCs don't follow the PC character creation rules, appropriate stats are just assigned by the author. 30 wounds seems reasonable for an enemy that is not expected to go down in 1 hit.

Comment: As long as it is being assigned by creators and not a typo then that works for me.